Optimizing plots with millions of points in jfreecharts
lately I've been really into plotting enormous realtime data, so in short I have a mysql database, where I store my data, it updates like for 1000 rows in a sec, I take two columns via jdbc with select and plot it in my jfreecharts data, this process of plotting and getting new info has its own frequency, for now it's like 200ms, so the question is: how can I plot this much points for like 8 hours straight with saving previous points
The result now is like 300k points without lagging, but there is surely a lack of optimizing rn
UPD: here is some code:
public Chart_module() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Канал " + i, true, true);
        seriesMap.put(i, series);
        fullSeriesMap.put(i, new XYSeries("Канал " + i, true, true));
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }

    loadInitialData();

    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateData();
        }
    }, 0, FREQUENCY);
}


public ChartPanel getChartPanel() {
    JFreeChart chart = createStyledChart(dataset);
    chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
    chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(false);
    chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(false);
    chartPanel.setAutoscrolls(true);
    chartPanel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override

        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

            if (e.getWheelRotation() != 0) {

                XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();

                double factor = Math.pow(1.4, e.getWheelRotation());

                plot.getDomainAxis().resizeRange(factor);

            }

        }

    });

    // Обработчик клавиатурных событий для переключения режимов

    chartPanel.setFocusable(true);
    // Добавление обработчика событий для горизонтального перемещения
    HorizontalPanMouseListener panListener = new HorizontalPanMouseListener(chartPanel);
    chartPanel.addMouseMotionListener(panListener);
    chartPanel.addMouseListener(panListener);

    // Добавление обработчика события двойного клика для возврата к последним точкам данных
    panListener.addDoubleClickReset(chartPanel);

    return chartPanel;
}



private static JFreeChart createStyledChart(XYSeriesCollection dataset) {
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "", "Time (hh:mm:ss)", "Data Value", dataset);

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();

    // Настройка цвета фона области построения
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.black);

    // Настройка осей
    DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("");
    domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"));
    domainAxis.setAutoRange(true);
    domainAxis.setFixedAutoRange(10000);
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("");
    rangeAxis.setLowerBound(0);
    rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true);
    plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
    plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);

    // Создание рендерера

    return chart;
}

// Начальная видимая область
private void loadInitialData() {
    String query = "SELECT id, channel_N, data_value, control_dev_time FROM data_response ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000";

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
         ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            int channelN = resultSet.getInt("channel_N");
            double dataValue = resultSet.getDouble("data_value");
            long controlDevTime = resultSet.getLong("control_dev_time");

            XYSeries series = seriesMap.get(channelN);
            if (series != null) {
                long millis = TimeConverter.convertNanoTimeToMillis(controlDevTime);
                series.addOrUpdate(millis, dataValue);
                fullSeriesMap.get(channelN).addOrUpdate(millis, dataValue); // Сохраняем в полную серию
            }
            lastProcessedId = id;
        }
        System.out.println("Initial data loaded. Last processed ID: " + lastProcessedId);

        // Запуск `loadRemainingData` в отдельном потоке после завершения начальной загрузки данных
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(this::loadRemainingData);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Оставшееся
private void loadRemainingData() {
    int batchSize = 30000; // Размер пакета
    int offset = 0;

    while (true) {
        String query = "SELECT id, channel_N, data_value, control_dev_time FROM data_response ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, batchSize);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, offset);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if (!resultSet.next()) {
                    boolean remainingDataLoaded = true;
                    break;
                }

                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                    int channelN = resultSet.getInt("channel_N");
                    double dataValue = resultSet.getDouble("data_value");
                    long controlDevTime = resultSet.getLong("control_dev_time");

                    XYSeries series = seriesMap.get(channelN);
                    if (series != null) {
                        long millis = TimeConverter.convertNanoTimeToMillis(controlDevTime);
                        series.add(millis, dataValue);
                        fullSeriesMap.get(channelN).addOrUpdate(millis, dataValue); // Сохраняем в полную серию
                    }
                }
                offset += batchSize;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Remaining data loaded.");
}

private static void updateData() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        String query = "SELECT id, channel_N, data_value, control_dev_time FROM data_response WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC";
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, lastProcessedId);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                    int channelN = resultSet.getInt("channel_N");
                    double dataValue = resultSet.getDouble("data_value");
                    long controlDevTime = resultSet.getLong("control_dev_time");

                    XYSeries series = seriesMap.get(channelN);
                    if (series != null) {
                        long millis = TimeConverter.convertNanoTimeToMillis(controlDevTime);
                        series.addOrUpdate(millis, dataValue);
                        fullSeriesMap.get(channelN).addOrUpdate(millis, dataValue); // Сохраняем в полную серию
                    }
                    lastProcessedId = id;
                }
                System.out.println("Fetched new data. Last processed ID: " + lastProcessedId);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

public void setSeriesVisibility(XYSeries series, boolean isVisible) {
    if (series != null) {
        if (isVisible && !dataset.getSeries().contains(series)) {
            dataset.addSeries(series);
            System.out.println("Series " + series.getKey() + " is now visible.");
        } else if (!isVisible && dataset.getSeries().contains(series)) {
            dataset.removeSeries(series);
            System.out.println("Series " + series.getKey() + " is now hidden.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Series not found.");
    }
}

public XYSeries getSeries(int channel) {
    return seriesMap.get(channel);
}
static class HorizontalPanMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private final ChartPanel chartPanel;
    private int lastX;
    private boolean panning;

    public HorizontalPanMouseListener(ChartPanel chartPanel) {
        this.chartPanel = chartPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            lastX = e.getX();
            panning = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            panning = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (panning) {
            int deltaX = lastX - e.getX();
            lastX = e.getX();
            XYPlot plot = chartPanel.getChart().getXYPlot();
            DateAxis domainAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
            double range = domainAxis.getRange().getLength();
            double shift = range * deltaX / chartPanel.getWidth() * 10;
            domainAxis.setRange(domainAxis.getLowerBound() + shift, domainAxis.getUpperBound() + shift);
        }
    }




    private void addDoubleClickReset(ChartPanel chartPanel) {
        chartPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    XYPlot plot = chartPanel.getChart().getXYPlot();
                    DateAxis domainAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
                    domainAxis.setAutoRange(true); // Включаем автообновление оси
                    // Опционально можно добавить другие настройки для возврата к последним точкам данных
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

}

Separating data acquisition from visualization is a good start. Optimizing the latter depends a lot on the domain. Thumbnails, examined here, is just one approach to navigation. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that focuses on a  particular problem you encounter. Are you using [jfreechart] or [jfreechart-fx]?

Adding to what @trashgod said, it is recommended to read [ask]. Why are you so sure there is a way to optimize it? Add that explanation to the question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As an aside, your fragment is incorrectly synchronized; it updates the chart on a thread other than the event dispatch thread; one alternative is examined here.

Looking closer, I see that you are querying the database on the event dispatch thread; instead, consider populating the dataset in the background and then updating the plot in your implementation of process; also consider JDBCXYDataset, cited here.
